# CSS: Put an image on the back of the other

Tags: html, css

I am working on a folding project (like folding a flyer). I am folding an image, but when the back is showed I want it to show another image.

Here is the code with just one image:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Double Gate Fold</title>
    <style>
        .view {
            width: 1024px;
            height: 612px;
            margin: 10px;
            position: relative;
            top: 100px;
            -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            -moz-perspective: 1000px;
            -o-perspective: 1000px;
            -ms-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
        }

            .view .slice {
                width: 256px;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 100;
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
                -moz-transform-origin: left center;
                -o-transform-origin: left center;
                -ms-transform-origin: left center;
                transform-origin: left center;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in-out;
                transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
                -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
                -o-backface-visibility: visible;
                -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
                backface-visibility: visible;
            }

            .view .s2,
            .view .s3, .view .s4 {
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0);
                -moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0);
            }

            .view .s1 {
                background-position: 0px 0px;
            }

            .view .s2 {
                background-position: -256px 0px;
            }

            .view .s3 {
                background-position: -512px 0px;
            }

            .view .s4 {
                background-position: -768px 0px;
            }

            .view:hover .s1 {
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,130deg);
                /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);*/
            }

            .view:hover .s2 {
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-60deg);
                /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);*/
            }

            .view:hover .s3 {
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-60deg);
                /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);*/
            }

            .view:hover .s4 {
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
                /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);*/
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="view">
        <div class="slice s1" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg); ">
            <div class="slice s2" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg); ">
                <div class="slice s3" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg); ">
                    <div class="slice s4" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg);">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking forward for your answers :)

Comment: ok, and what have you tried so far ? :)

Comment: I have tried to make another set of divs but with another slice and then just copy and paste the code for the other slices. But it is not working every time

Comment: "But it is not working every time" but works sometimes?? please add a jsfiddle to show what you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are more simple solutions but I achieved it with pseudo-elements.

Like this:

```css
.view {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 612px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.view .slice {
    width: 256px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    -ms-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
    -o-backface-visibility: visible;
    -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
    backface-visibility: visible;
}
.view .s2, .view .s3, .view .s4 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0);
}
.view .s1 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.view .s2 {
    background-position: -256px 0px;
}
.view .s3 {
    background-position: -512px 0px;
}
.view .s4 {
    background-position: -768px 0px;
}
.view:hover .s1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 130deg);
    /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);*/
}
.view:hover .s2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -60deg);
    /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);*/
}
.view:hover .s3 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -60deg);
    /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);*/
}
.view:hover .s4 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(256px, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -110deg);
    /*-moz-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -o-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
                transform: translate3d(256px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);*/
}

.view .s4:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.view:hover .s4:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
.view .s1:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/100x150');
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.view:hover .s1:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="view">
        <div class="slice s1" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg); ">
            <div class="slice s2" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg); ">
                <div class="slice s3" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg); ">
                    <div class="slice s4" style="background-image: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/ec30/i/2011/178/e/b/the_majestic_grey_wolf_by_picturebypali-d3k5dxp.jpg);"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It's not perfect but its a way of doing it.

Comment: Actually I just found out that it is not working as it should. If you put an image between the brackets of "background: url();" on the last slice it's the same image as on the first slice

Comment: what? they are two different images.. haven't you placed the same image on the url?

Comment: @Deni2994 edit with 2 different images and its working.

Comment: I know but that means that I have to cut the main picture in 4 parts and put each part in the corresponding slice.